# Intersection of closed geodesics in hyperbolic surface

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, curves-and-surfaces

This question may be easy but I could not come up with a proof.

Let $F$ be a hyperbolic surface of finite type (with finitely many boundary and finitely many puncture). Let $\gamma$ be a closed non-simple geodesic. $\gamma$ is not homotopic to a point, a puncture or a boundary. Let $p$ be a self intersection point of $\gamma.$

**1) Can there be a  simple closed geodesic passing through $p$?**

If not then

**2) Can there be a closed geodesic passing through $p$ different from $\gamma$?**

Comment: I do not get question 2: $\gamma$ is a closed geodesic passing through $p$!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to (1) is yes.

Take $P$ a hyperbolic surface with one geodesic boundary, called $\delta$, and two punctures.  Form $S$, a sphere with four punctures, by doubling $P$ across $\delta$.  Note that $S$ has a reflection symmetry $f$ that fixes $\delta$ pointwise. Let $\gamma$ be a figure of eight curve, about two of the punctures of $S$, choosen so that the reflection $f$ fixes $\gamma$ setwise.  Deduce that the self-intersection point $p \in \gamma$ lies on $\delta$.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Can this happen in closed surface?

Comment: Yes.  Replace the punctures by equal length geodesic boundary components.  Do the above, and then glue to get a surface of genus two.